# Connection timed out

Tags: java, android, couchdb, localhost

I'm am attempting to run Spika-Android and when I try to sign up I get this error.

[image]

Here's the portion of code that corresponds to the issue.

```
package com.cloverstudio.spika.utils;

/**
 * Const
 * 
 * This class contains all of the constant variables used through the
 * application.
 */
public class Const {

/* Debug/Production variables */
public static final boolean IS_DEBUG = true;

/* CouchDB credentials */
public static final String BASE_URL                 = "http://10.0.2.2:5983/";
public static final String SUPPORT_USER             = "1";
public static final String API_URL                  = BASE_URL;
public static final String AUTH_URL                 = BASE_URL + "auth?";
public static final String SEARCH_USERS_URL         = BASE_URL + "searchUsers?";
public static final String SEARCH_GROUPS_URL        = BASE_URL + "searchGroups/name/";
public static final String FILE_UPLOADER_URL        = BASE_URL + "fileuploader";
public static final String FILE_DOWNLOADER_URL      = BASE_URL + "filedownloader?";
public static final String CHECKUNIQUE_URL          = BASE_URL + "checkUnique?";
public static final String FIND_USER_BY_NAME        = BASE_URL + "findUser/name/";
public static final String FIND_USER_BY_EMAIL       = BASE_URL + "findUser/email/";
public static final String FIND_USER_BY_ID          = BASE_URL + "findUser/id/";
public static final String FIND_USERACTIVITY_SUMMARY= BASE_URL + "activitySummary";
public static final String GET_AVATAR_FILE_ID       = BASE_URL + "GetAvatarFileId/";
public static final String FIND_MESSAGE_BY_ID       = BASE_URL + "findMessageById/";
public static final String FIND_COMMENTS_BY_MESSAGE_ID  = BASE_URL + "comments/";
public static final String COMMENTS_COUNT           = BASE_URL + "commentsCount/";
public static final String FIND_USER_MESSAGES       = BASE_URL + "userMessages/";
public static final String FIND_GROUP_MESSAGES      = BASE_URL + "groupMessages/";
public static final String FIND_ALL_EMOTICONS       = BASE_URL + "Emoticons";
public static final String FIND_GROUP_BY_ID         = BASE_URL + "findGroup/id/";
public static final String FIND_GROUP_BY_NAME       = BASE_URL + "findGroup/name/";
public static final String FIND_GROUP_BY_CATEGORY_ID= BASE_URL + "findGroup/categoryId/";
public static final String FIND_GROUP_CATEGORIES    = BASE_URL + "findAllGroupCategory";


public static final String PASSWORDREMINDER_URL     = BASE_URL + "resetPassword?";
public static final String UNREGISTER_PUSH_URL      = BASE_URL + "unregistToken?";
public static final String DATABASE                 = "spikademo";

public static final String CREATE_USER              = "create_user";
public static final String UPDATE_USER              = "updateUser";
public static final String SEND_MESSAGE_TO_USER     = "sendMessageToUser";
public static final String SEND_MESSAGE_TO_GROUP    = "sendMessageToGroup";
public static final String SEND_COMMENT             = "sendComment";
public static final String CREATE_GROUP             = "createGroup";
public static final String SUBSCRIBE_GROUP          = "subscribeGroup";
public static final String UNSUBSCRIBE_GROUP        = "unSubscribeGroup";
public static final String DELETE_GROUP             = "deleteGroup";
public static final String UPDATE_GROUP             = "updateGroup";
public static final String WATCH_GROUP              = "watchGroup";
public static final String UNWATCH_GROUP            = "unWatchGroup";
public static final String ADD_CONTACT              = "addContact";
public static final String REMOVE_CONTACT           = "removeContact";
public static final String SET_DELETE               = "setDelete";

/* User constants */
public static final String FAVORITE_GROUPS = "favorite_groups";
public static final String CONTACTS = "contacts";
public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String EMAIL = "email";
public static final String LAST_LOGIN = "last_login";
public static final String USER = "user";
public static final String USER_AVATAR = "avatar.jpg";
public static final String ABOUT = "about";
public static final String BIRTHDAY = "birthday";
public static final String GENDER = "gender";
public static final String MALE = "male";
public static final String FEMALE = "female";
public static final String ONLINE = "online";
public static final String OFFLINE = "offline";
public static final String AWAY = "away";
public static final String BUSY = "busy";
public static final String ANDROID_PUSH_TOKEN = "android_push_token";
public static final String TOKEN = "token";
public static final String TOKEN_TIMESTAMP = "token_timestamp";
public static final String AVATAR_NAME = "avatar_name";
public static final String ONLINE_STATUS = "online_status";
public static final String MAX_CONTACT_COUNT = "max_contact_count";
public static final String MAX_FAVORITE_COUNT = "max_favorite_count";

public static final int MAX_CONTACTS = 20;
public static final int MAX_FAVORITES = 10;

/* Message constants */
public static final String MESSAGE_TYPE = "message_type";
public static final String TEXT = "text";
public static final String IMAGE = "image";
public static final String VOICE = "voice";
public static final String VIDEO = "video";
public static final String LOCATION = "location";
public static final String EMOTICON = "emoticon";
public static final String NEWS = "news";
public static final String MODIFIED = "modified";
public static final String FROM_USER_NAME = "from_user_name";
public static final String FROM_USER_ID = "from_user_id";
public static final String VALID = "valid";
public static final String MESSAGE_TARGET_TYPE = "message_target_type";
public static final String CREATED = "created";
public static final String TO_USER_NAME = "to_user_name";
public static final String TO_USER_ID = "to_user_id";
public static final String BODY = "body";
public static final String LATITUDE = "latitude";
public static final String LONGITUDE = "longitude";
public static final String COMMENTS = "comments";
public static final String EMOTICON_IMAGE_URL = "emoticon_image_url";
public static final String _ATTACHMENTS = "_attachments";
public static final String TO_GROUP_ID = "to_group_id";
public static final String TO_GROUP_NAME = "to_group_name";
public static final String USER_IMAGE_URL = "user_image_url";
public static final String DELETE_TYPE = "delete_type";
public static final String DELETE_AT = "delete_at";

/* Group constants */
public static final String GROUP = "group";
public static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String USER_ID = "user_id";
public static final String GROUP_AVATAR = "group_image.jpg";
public static final String GROUP_PASSWORD= "group_password";
public static final String CATEGORY_ID = "category_id";
public static final String CATEGORY_NAME = "category_name";
public static final String DELETED = "deleted";

/* Group category constants */
public static final String GROUP_CATEGORY = "group_category";
public static final String TITLE = "title";
public static final String GROUP_CATEGORY_AVATAR = "picture.png";

/* User group constants */
public static final String USER_GROUP = "user_group";
public static final String GROUP_ID = "group_id";
public static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";

/* General constants */
public static final String ROWS = "rows";
public static final String KEY = "key";
public static final String VALUE = "value";
public static final String ATTACHMENTS = "_attachments";
public static final String OK = "ok";
public static final String REV = "rev";
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String DOC = "doc";
public static final String TYPE = "type";
public static final String NULL = "null";
public static final String _ID = "_id";
public static final String _REV = "_rev";
public static final String DATA = "data";
public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "content_type";
public static final String REVPOS = "revpos";
public static final String STUB = "stub";
public static final String LENGTH = "length";


/* Recent activity constants */
public static final String ACTIVITY_SUMMARY = "activity_summary";
public static final String RECENT_ACTIVITY = "recent_activity";
public static final String TARGET_ID = "target_id";
public static final String TARGET_TYPE = "target_type";
public static final String NOTIFICATIONS = "notifications";
public static final String MESSAGES = "messages";
public static final String MESSAGE = "message";
public static final String COUNT = "count";

/* Comment constants */
public static final String COMMENT = "comment";
public static final String MESSAGE_ID = "message_id";

/* Push notification constants */
public static final String PUSH_SENDER_ID = "231801848270";
public static final String PUSH_MESSAGE = "message";
public static final String PUSH_FROM_USER_ID = "fromUser";
public static final String PUSH_FROM_NAME= "fromUserName";
public static final String PUSH_FROM_GROUP_ID = "groupId";
public static final String PUSH_FROM_TYPE = "type";
public static final String PUSH_TYPE_USER = "user";
public static final String PUSH_TYPE_GROUP = "group";

public static final String SIGN_IN = "sign_in";
public static final String PUSH_INTENT = "push_intent";

/* hookup://user/[ime korisnika] URI constant */
public static final String USER_URI_INTENT = "user_uri_intent";
public static final String USER_URI_NAME = "user_uri_name";

/* hookup://group/[ime grupe] URI constant */
public static final String GROUP_URI_INTENT = "group_uri_intent";
public static final String GROUP_URI_NAME = "group_uri_name";

/* Login error */
public static final String LOGIN_ERROR = "login";
public static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS = "login_success";

/* Crittercism constants */
public static final String CRITTERCISM_APP_ID = "51938f2e97c8f20789000010";

/* Display image size constants */
public static final int PROFILE_REQUIRED_SIZE = 400;
public static final int LIST_AVATAR_REQUIRED_SIZE = 140;
public static final int PICTURE_SIZE = 640;
public static final int AVATAR_THUMB_SIZE = 120;
public static final int PICTURE_THUMB_SIZE = 240;

/* File handler constants */
public static final String FILE = "file";
public static final String AVATAR_FILE_ID = "avatar_file_id";
public static final String AVATAR_THUMB_FILE_ID = "avatar_thumb_file_id";
public static final String PICTURE_FILE_ID = "picture_file_id";
public static final String PICTURE_THUMB_FILE_ID = "picture_thumb_file_id";
public static final String VOICE_FILE_ID = "voice_file_id";
public static final String VIDEO_FILE_ID = "video_file_id";
public static final String TMP_BITMAP_FILENAME = "hutmpfile.jpeg";
public static final String UPLOADS = "uploads";

/* Recording constants */
public static final long MAX_RECORDING_TIME_VIDEO = 30; // seconds
public static final long MAX_RECORDING_TIME_VOICE = 180000; // milliseconds

/* Watching group log constants */
public static final String WATCHING_GROUP_LOG = "watching_group_log";

/* Error constants */
public static final String ERROR = "error";
public static final String INVALID_TOKEN = "Invalid token";
```

}

In my logcat I get this error.

`02-14 20:48:30.344: E/error(1612): Connect to /10.0.2.2:5983 timed out`

My IP was `127.0.0.1:5983`, but I heard that I have to change it, so  I changed it to `10.0.2.2:5983`. I'm also using couchDB. Any help would be appreciated and if you need anymore details, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to make the server code of spika to run, so i hope i could help you a bit and matbe you could also help me.

Well about your issue here at the next link - http://www.spikaapp.com/en/build/android

You can see you need to change two line at your code -

```
public static final String BASE_URL         = "http://localhost:8080/wwwroot/api/";
public static final String INFORMATION_URL=  "http://localhost:8080/wwwroot/page/information";
```

So i wouuld say you need to add the next bits-

```
public static final String BASE_URL         = "http://10.0.2.2:5983/wwwroot/api/";
public static final String INFORMATION_URL=  "http://10.0.2.2:5983/wwwroot/page/information";
```

Hope this will help you